# Angular JS UI sample app not working

Tags: angularjs

I tried the UI Router sample application (plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview) but when i'm running the same code in my browser, it's not working. Any recent changes to API ? Till "  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")" It's working as it's routed to "/route1" initially.

[image: working like this]

Additional Files with index.html (in same directory):

- route1.html
- route1.list.html
- route2.html
- route2.list.html

  ```
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
  myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

    $stateProvider
      .state('route1', {
          url: "/route1",
          templateUrl: "route1.html"
      })
        .state('route1.list', {
            url: "/list",
            templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
            controller: function($scope){
              $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
            }
        })

      .state('route2', {
          url: "/route2",
          templateUrl: "route2.html"
      })
        .state('route2.list', {
            url: "/list",
            templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
            controller: function($scope){
              $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
            }
        })
  })
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS loads templates via ajax calls and such calls can be only made by browser when it runs a page from server, loading your application from a filesystem (`file:///` in address bar) won't work.

You can use a simple server e.g. `python -m http.server`

Comment: means what changes need to be made ?

Comment: Just open: http://embed.plnkr.co/u18KQc/preview - it should work that way. It doesn't handle being inside iframe well.

Comment: It's working on plnkr, i'm talking about when i downloaded the code & run it on my PC as it is, it's not working ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't get that. Did you try running it from a local server? (instead from filesystem) I'll edit the answer out to reflect that suggestion.

Comment: I just double clicked on index.html to run the downloaded file, it wssnt able to load the CDN files as it;s without http so i downloaded but still it;s not working ! Neither other angular projects downloaded !

Comment: Oops man ! my bad, i dint run it on localhost, it's working this way, update the answer as run it on localhost on on filesystem ! but the html, css & JS should work directly without localhost ?